# Python logging exceptions with traceback, but without displaying messages twice

Tags: python, logging, exception, output

If I run the following code:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('creator')
try:
    # some stuff
except Exception as exception:
    logger.exception(exception)
```

I get the following output on the screen:

```
creator     : ERROR    division by zero
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/graph_creator.py", line 21, in run
    1/0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

**Are there ways to get such a output?**

```
creator     : ERROR    ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/graph_creator.py", line 21, in run
    1/0
```

Of course, I can get this (but I don't like it):

```
creator     : ERROR    Сaught exception (and etc...)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/graph_creator.py", line 21, in run
    1/0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Comment: Saw your comment. You need to take the custom `Formatter` approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you called `exception` like this:

```
logger.exception('%s: %s', exception.__class__.__name__, exception)
```

then you could get the exception class name in the initial line.

If you need more precise changes, you can use a custom `Formatter` subclass which formats things exactly as you like. This would need to override `format_exception` to change the formatting of the traceback.

Comment: and in my log file I got 'ZeroDivisionError: division by zero' twice, above and after traceback, I need just above